# Error -6003 on building setup with installshield 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield-2010

I want to create a setup with **InstallShield 2010** for my winform application.
I have created an **InstallScript MSI Project** and add all files and folders of my application to it.Also i have set Microsoft .net framework 4 full and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express as Prerequisites.

Note: Microsoft OLE 2.40 for windows NT and windows 95 and Microsoft GDI+ are checked as default Prerequisites too.

But i receive these following errors when i want to build the setup :

```
Error -6003: An error occurred streaming 'C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2010\SetupPrerequisites\WindowsImagingComponent\x86\wic_x86_enu.exe' into setup.exe

Error -6003: An error occurred streaming 'C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2010\SetupPrerequisites\WindowsImagingComponent\x64\wic_x64_enu.exe' into setup.exe

Error -6003: An error occurred streaming 'C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2010\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer\3.1\x86\WindowsServer2003-KB898715-x86-enu.exe' into setup.exe
```

and some other errors like above.

Comment: I take it the prerequisites exist at the path specified?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by installing the redistributables in your computer.
In your installer project go to 2.Specify Application Data ->Redistributables.
In the list, you may have some elemetns selected. They will be shown in the Location file "Needs to be downloaded". Make right click over the element and select "Download selected Item".